# Kill and destroy activity

Tags: android, android-activity, kill, destroy

The first screen of my application is a login screen, so I used the method **finish ()** after user have logged. However when i return the application I would like to be already logged. I tried to use **onDestroy ()**, but without success.

Comment: be specific ...really unclear question ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be better if you implement your logic otherwise. The first screen in your application can be HomeScreenActivity in which you'll check if the user is logged and start LoginActivity if needed.

```
public class HomeScreenActivity extends Activity {

    /* some declaration */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* some other stuff */
        if (!userIsLogged()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

See [Data Storage on Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: SharedPreferences are bomb.com

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png)...   Furthermore SharedPreferences can be used to save username/login details but im of the understanding that they can be accessed by any application, so be careful what you put there.